# How to change the mesh of the character in UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, 3d-meshes, mesh, fbx

I made a Bellsprout mesh in Blender, exported it as an FBX file, and imported it into UE4.

I can insert it in the stage without problem, but I would like to use this Bellsprout mesh to replace the mesh of the built-in character.

[image]

Even clicking and dragging will not replace the mesh:

[image]

I've looked into importing between blender/UE4: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Static_Mesh_from_Blender

And also about mesh editing: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Content/Types/StaticMeshes/Editor

I also looked at some questions in this forum: [Changing rendering in UE4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134967/changing-rendering-in-ue4) and [Making only parts of a mesh destroy in UE4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117446/making-only-parts-of-a-mesh-destroy-in-ue4)

To see if the question had not already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh you've imported appears to be a static mesh, whereas the character expects a *skeletal* mesh (one that supports animation).

Your options are basically to

- re-export your character model as a skeletal mesh or
- modify the character Blueprint to change the type of the mesh component from SkeletalMeshComponent to StaticMeshComponent.

The first option is probably the simpler one, as changing the mesh component type will likely break functionality related to triggering and dealing with animations that you may need to fix up before the Blueprint will compile.

[Here is a guide](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Creating_a_Skeletal_Mesh_in_Blender) on making a skeletal mesh in Blender. I can't vouch for its utility, but it might provide a starting point for handling the export.